# Question about UIWebView for use in my help screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I made a UIWebView and I had it read a local help.html file. 
This is for my app's help screen.

Now my question is two-fold:

1. if I say have a link in there to go to either my website
   or something then people click that link and it's within the uiwebview! How
   would I go about launching safari instead? target='_blank' doesn't seem to work.
2. If I want a link to the paid version of my app in there would it launch some 
   kind of other program? I don't want my help screen to turn into a web browser (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari) answers your first question. I.e. use

   `-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType`
2. You could choose to open that link with a Safari, like your question 1, or somehow intercept the link and do something you like use the same method mentioned above.