# iphone app, how to open links in safari within webview from HTML not recoding app

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

ok, i'm not asking how to modify my existing iphone app to make this happen, i can do that. i am trying to make links that i have showing up in my app's existing webview open in Safari instead of the existing webview as was originally designed. I want to make this work for existing app users that don't upgrade.

so in my webview i load a page on my server that has html links... is there any code (tag, class, html, java, etc) that i can use that will cause these links to be opened in Safari and not just within the webview?

thanks for the help. i've been looking all over, no luck... yet-

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can open another application from your app is to use the openURL method on UIApplication:  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari))

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]
```

Unfortunately this means you can't make Safari launch instead of your webview via some change to the HTML content.  It will require an update to your app.

Taking a step back this makes sense given that such a feature would allow web developers to hijack non-safari-browser apps forcing them to use Safari.  It probably wouldn't even make sense to do so, but it would lead to some confusion on the end-user's part, and maybe there's some security implications too.

Comment: thanks, ya, that snippet didn't do it and it doesn't look like there's anything that acts like the mailto: and tel: links to trigger safari and i can't redirect that webview page.