# Open a link in safari without closing the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If my user presses a button to send an email, it opens a new email message inside my app and then when they press send or cancel, returns them to where they were. How can i allow them to do this same thing with pressing a button to send them to a webpage in safari, then back again?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement your own browser (which is actually not hard to do).

One thing to keep in mind, though, is that if you include a browser your app will have a rating of 17+, limiting your market somewhat.

Comment: Is that still the case? I didn't get a 17+ warning when I installed Tweetbot a month ago, which has a built-in browser.

Comment: Not if you limit the websites that can be reached. You can get the rating back down to 4+ this way.

Answer (score 4):

Use a webView instead if you want the user to stay within your app.

Comment: Yep.... I second this +1. You want to probably build a basic browser using UIWebView.... Implementing forward and back buttons and a simple address bar with a stop and reload button isn't hard to do at all.