# ios webview open link in different tab/webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have two tabs (things that are at the bottom of the 'Clock' app) both have webviews. how can I make a link that was clicked on first tab's webview be opened (and show to user) in second tab second webview if there is a string "test" in the URL.

thnak you!

Comment: I am not iOS developer, if anyone can point me to a simple solution, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set a delegate on your UIWebView and then handle the delegate method to be able to intercept the click and send it to the tab you want.

Here's an example: [UIWebView open links in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari/2899793#2899793)

Comment: good answer, and link to sample is almost what I needed. Thank you!