# WebView, opening link in different window/tab

Tags: uiwebview, mobile-safari

Is it possible to open a link like this to be opened in Safari by only changing the contents of the HTML file only?

My WebView loads a local HTML page with this source:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/exampleFanPage" target="_blank">Link to Fanpage</a>
```

How do I make it so that it opens in Safari? By default it should also open in Facebook app if it was downloaded?

It's annoying that it opens the Facebook page on the same webview and the user won't be able to go back to the previous webpage.

Would I have to face a new approach? Thank you.

I looked at other solutions but I don't know what it means by adding a delegate to the webview?

Comment: If you don't know what it means to add the web view's delegate, then read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html as the scope of knowledge you need is significantly wider than what a single Stack Overflow answer can provide. Also, please read the [Xcode tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info) as it's inappropriate for your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView open links in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get get back-history working with anchors on iOS? I have been dealing with the same issue.

Thanks to inspiration from http://www.bennadel.com/, created the following angular directive that fixes this back-history issue. Basically it overrides the default html anchor behavior.

```
    .directive('anchorOpenInNewWin',function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            link : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
                $element.bind('click touchstart',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    location.href = $attrs.href;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    <a anchor-open-in-new-win href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

This solution could be easily translated into jquery or whatever you are using. Hope this helps