# How open link in App WebView (xCode5) to Safari.app

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, hyperlink, safari

I just created an application made with WebView me but all the links open in the same application.

as how I can open. pdf in safari browser?

example:

to open link in facebook we use: fb://profile/257099684360698

to open link in twitter we use: twitter://user?id= 90748900

There is something to open on safari?

e.g: "safari://"

*excuse my bad English.*

Comment: you won't be able to see the pdf as it is in the sandbox of your app and safari is a different app

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `UIWebView` delegate:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari) on SO.

Comment: example:

to open link in facebook we use: fb://profile/257099684360698

to open link in twitter we use: twitter://user?id= 90748900

There is something to open on safari?

e.g: "safari://"

excuse my bad English.

Comment: you can pass through file:// requests which would be relative links.

Comment: so, in the html i can use:   <a href="file://www.google.com/example.pdf">pdf.</a>   only that?