# Open external url in Ionicframework(Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to invoke the native browser in ionicframework to open a url without plugin.

the code:

```
if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    navigator.app.loadUrl(url, {openExternal : true});
}else if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    window.open(url, '_system');
}
```

In fact, app can invoke the browser in Android, but in ios, it will replace the current app view instead of open the browser.

Please suggest.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do something like this, looks like your device was not ready:-
Please use below given function (requires phonegap.js)

```
if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
 {
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() 
    {
     // open URL in default web browser
      var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system', 'location=yes');
    }
}
```

---

Below is some details regarding window.open function

**url**: The URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if the URL contains Unicode characters.
    var ref = window.open(url, target, options);

**Target**:  2nd parameter can be following :

_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.

_system: Opens in the system's web browser.

options: Options for the InAppBrowser. Optional, defaulting to: location=yes. (String)

The options string must not contain any blank space, and each feature's name/value pairs must be separated by a comma. Feature names are case insensitive. All platforms support the value below:

location: 
closebuttoncaption: 
clearcache: 
clearsessioncache:

Comment: This way have to add plugin `inappbrowser`, I have been add the plugin and solve this problem, maybe there is no way to achieve with native js code. thanks a lot.