# Cannot Open Safari Browser from Webviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I am opening links in Webviewcontroller. I have created a button on webview controller to open that link in Safari Browser. Problem I am facing is when I open url before it get load completely in web view controller, it open in Safari browser successfully. But when URL loaded completely in webview controller, it doesn't open Safari Broswer.

My Code is:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Open in Safari", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.openInSafari()
    }))

    if  (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone){
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:  NSLocalizedString("Cancel",comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler:nil))
    }
```

And Function to open Safari Browser:

```
func openInSafari(){

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: self.currentUrl)!, options: [:],completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: self.currentUrl)!)
    }

}
```

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Can you print the url in openInSafari function?

Comment: Yes Url is coming. Function is working properly as I check by applying breakpoint.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once:

```
guard let url = URL(string: self.currentUrl) else {
    return //be safe
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: may i know which ios version you are trying