# Playing a YouTube video in WebView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this library https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player (it uses JS API and WebView) to play YouTube videos in my `ViewController` but when you click on title of a video inside WebView it goes directly to YouTube site and you can't go back anymore (it should not go there in the first play though)

[image] [image]

Can I disable clicks or redirect these links to web-browser app (Safari in iOS) instead of opening them in my WebView (which is very annoying)

So my WebView isn't supposed to show YouTube site's pages but only a video

**update**

It seems we have add some filter, e.g. allow only the next links
`ytplayer://*`, `about:blank` and `https://www.youtube.com/embed/*`

[image: screenshot_1]

https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/blob/master/YouTubePlayer/YouTubePlayer/YouTubePlayer.swift#L344

**update 2**

Also when I click on a link next condition is always false

```
if navigationType == .linkClicked {
    if let url = request.url {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
    return false
}
```

[image]

Though when I press on the next link inside webview then this condition works and link is opened in Web-browser app:

[image]

So YouTube site isn't easy thing

Comment: You can use the WKNavigationDelegate to restrict navigating elsewhere yes

Comment: @Scriptable I've updated my question, seems I can't totally disable navigation but I can allow only the next addresses `ytplayer://*`, `about:blank` and `https://www.youtube.com/embed/*`

Comment: my solution is https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/issues/179#issuecomment-470947465