# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UIWebViewDelegate'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to utilize UIWebView functionality, specifically I want to do something like this: [Open links in Safari instead of UIWebVIew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452719/how-do-i-open-links-in-safari-instead-of-uiwebview)

But I am having an issue when I try and add the UIWebViewDelegate to my AppDelegate interface.

[image]

Anyone know what the issue is? Note this is Mac OS not iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyone know what the issue is? Note this is Mac OS not iOS.

That's the issue right there.

There is no `UIWebView` or `UIWebViewDelegate` on MacOS X. UI is the prefix for UIKit, which is the iOS equivalent of AppKit. When you see a class whose name begins with UI, you know immediately that you're looking at iOS code.

The class you're probably looking for is [`WebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `WebView` actually uses *five* separate delegates, so you may need to implement as many as five different protocols: `WebUIDelegate`, `WebDownload`, `WebFrameLoadDelegate`, `WebPolicyDelegate`, and `WebResourceLoadDelegate`. (In reality, I don't think you need to do quite that much work. For example, you may not need to implement your own access policy.)

Answer (score 7):

Add:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: and before add uikit to Build Phases

Answer (score 0):

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is iOS only. You cannot use a UIWebViewDelegate for Mac OSX. If you look at your own code, you are using a WebView, not a UIWebView.

You'll want to look at [the WebView class docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)