# How to force links to open in iOS Safari?

Tags: facebook, ios6, mobile-safari, mime-types, passbook

my webpage has links to download Passbook .pkpass files.
This works fine in Safari for iOS since Apple's browser supports the mime type: application.com/vnd.apple.pkpass

Facebook's iOS browser (as well as others) does not (yet) support this mime type. Therefore, if a user follows a link to my site from within Facebook, they can't download my Passbook files. However, if they click on 'Open in Safari' then they can download the file.

How can I code my webpage such that clicking on a link will force open Safari on iOS?

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

These headers should be helpful to what you're doing.

```
Content-Type "application/force-download"
Content-Description "File Transfer"
Content-Disposition attachment
ForceType "application/octet-stream"
```

I suggest you try to set them in your .htaccess or httpd.conf file with the following code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pkpass)$">
Header set Content-Type "application/force-download"
Header set Content-Description "File Transfer"
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
Header set ForceType "application/octet-stream"
</FilesMatch>
```

It's a little overkill, but will ensure the download is forced across all browsers. Change the pkpass to anything else to force the download of any other file type.

Comment: Misread your question, to force a download to open in safari, you will need to use this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/file.pkpass"]];   see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452719/how-do-i-open-links-in-safari-instead-of-uiwebview

Comment: That's not possible from a web-page, only from an iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find a way to do this yet. Somehow, forced pkpass downloads won't work in the Facebook mobile browser.

The best way is to guide the user to open the page in Safari.