# How to open a safari window from iPad application that is running a local website?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an **iPad** application that is loading a website locally. It works perfectly but the only problem is that I have a link to **Facebook** that when I click that, the **Facebook** page will be opened in the application window. Therefore I need to close my running application and reopen it to use it again. How can I open a new **Safari** window for this purpose?

**All files of the website are in application asset folder therefore once user opens the application would see the wesbsite**

```
 <a href="facebook address" target="_blank"><img src="facebook logo"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to launch safari and open URL from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app)

This is not my answer but I thought it could help (link to answer above...wasn't allowed to comment):

below is the answer from a member named Tim

Heres what I did:

I created an `IBAction` in the header .h files as follows:

```
- (IBAction)openDaleDietrichDotCom:(id)sender;
```

I added a `UIButton` on the Settings page containing the text that I want to link to.

I connected the button to `IBAction` in File Owner appropriately.

Then implement the following:

```
- (IBAction)openDaleDietrichDotCom:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.daledietrich.com"]];
}
```

Comment: and by Tim, I meant Dale Dietrich. Apologies

Comment: can I write this in html file? as I mentioned the application is opening a local website.

Comment: Hi Jack. From my limited knowledge and scouting, I found this answer that seems to say you should be able to depending on how you are loading your html:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452719/how-do-i-open-links-in-safari-instead-of-uiwebview/12103579#12103579][1]