# UIWebView, tying an action to a href link

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

We have an "About our app" popover that is html formatted and basically a UIWebView in a popover.  There's also a href link to our website.  The problem is if you click on the link, it just opens up our website in the popover.  Is there a way to alter what happens for that link, like open up Safari so it's in a full browser, or at least increase the popover size since our About our App window is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532453/force-a-webview-link-to-launch-safari) gives the following code for every http, https and mailto call to open in Safari:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; 
{
    NSURL *requestURL =[ [ request URL ] retain ]; 
    if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ]) 
             && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) { 
       return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ]; 
    } 
    [ requestURL release ]; 
    return YES; 
}
```

You can modify for only certain URLs by getting the URL from the request.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to open URL via UIWebView:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView_ shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    self.curURL = request.URL;

    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"file"])
    {
        return YES;
    }

    UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Open in Safari", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];

    return NO;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Action sheet delegate methods


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex + eSafariButtonIndex)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.curURL];    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method of the UIWebView delegate?

The webview should ask its delegate each time it loads another frame / page, so if you click on the link the method is called.

You then just have to return `NO` and handle the request the way you want !